How do I import Excel VBA modules programmatically using Excel VBA?
I have a folder (the active workbook's file path) that holds multiple .bas files. Some of these .bas file names match the module names in an Excel workbook and some do not.
I need to create a macro that will loop through all of the .bas files in the folder and if the name of the .bas files match any modules, the modules should be replaced with their respective .bas files, ensuring the names of the modules remain unchanged.
I have scoured the web and tried to make my code work but have had no luck. Below is an example of what I have tried. My code only words for the first two .bas files in the folder and doesn’t update the name from the standard Module1 and Module2 names.
Sub import()

Dim path, file As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
file = Dir(path & "*.bas")

On Error Resume Next

Do While Len(file) > 0

    For Each Module In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If Module.Name = Left(file, Len(file) - 4) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Module
            Dim import As Object
            Object = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.import(path & file)
            Object.Name = Left(file, Len(file) - 4)
        End If
    Next Module

    file = Dir
    
Loop

End Sub

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Do you get an error if you remove on error resume next. I guess Object and Modul are key words and shoud not used as variable names.

After changing line 11 to Set Object = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.import(path & file) I still have the issue of my code not working for anything beyond the first two .bas files.

Yes Shrotter, the error I get is 'Run-time error 50021: Application-defined or object-defined error'

Set import = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.import(path & file)

okay, updated code with all suggestions, but still can't get it to work for beyond two .bas files in the folder.

Tested with 3 modules
Sub import()

    Dim m As Object, filename As String, msg As String
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each m In .VBProject.VBComponents
            filename = .path & "\" & m.Name & ".bas"
            If Dir(filename) <> "" Then
                msg = msg & vbLf & m.Name
                .VBProject.VBComponents.Remove m
                .VBProject.VBComponents.import filename
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
       MsgBox "Modules updated" & msg, vbInformation
    Else
       MsgBox "No modules updated", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub


Strangely, your code still only works for 2 modules for me. Also, the module names that are imported have the standard Module1 and Module2 code names instead of matching the .bas file names. Thanks. I'm still racking my brain with it.

@user21948159 What version of OS and Excel do you have ? Do you know which module it fails on, if so try without that one.

I'm on Windows 11 Office 365. Excluding the dodgy module and trying with just the two modules that do work, I get the desired result bar the module names

@user21948159 Do you get the correct names if you import the 3 modules manually into a new blank workbook ?

No, importing the modules manually returns an error. I think it has to do with the fact that the .bas files were created outside of excel. When I test with macros that were first exported by excel then import them again, that works. Ideally, I would like to import .bas files that were externally created, but it looks like that's not possible.

@user21948159 You could use a diff program like the one in https://tortoisesvn.net/ to compare the created module with one exported from excel that has been copy/pasted.

I prefer to make a more generic solution:
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub ImportModule(wb As Workbook, Path As String, Optional ReplaceOnly As Boolean, Optional ModuleType As String = "bas")
    Path = Path & "\"
        
    Dim FileName As String, BaseName As String
    FileName = Dir(Path & "*." & ModuleType)
    Dim Module As Object
    
    With wb.VBProject
        Do While Len(FileName) > 0
            BaseName = Left(FileName, Len(FileName) - Len(ModuleType) - 1)
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Module = .VBComponents(BaseName)
            On Error GoTo 0
        
            If ReplaceOnly And Not Module Is Nothing Then
                .VBComponents.Remove Module
                .VBComponents.Import Path & FileName
            ElseIf Not ReplaceOnly Then
                If Not Module Is Nothing Then .VBComponents.Remove Module
                .VBComponents.Import Path & FileName
            End If
        
            Set Module = Nothing
            FileName = Dir
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
    
Sub Test()
    ImportModule ThisWorkbook, "V:\Code Modules\Temp\", ReplaceOnly:=False
End Sub

Addendum
I added this section to handle the filenames not matching the Attribute VB_Name (module name).
Code
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceModules(wb As Workbook, Path As String, Optional ModuleType As String = "bas")
    Path = Path & "\"
        
    Dim FileName As String, VBName As String, Contents As String
    FileName = Dir(Path & "*." & ModuleType)
    Dim Module As Object
    
    With wb.VBProject
        Do While Len(FileName) > 0
            Contents = GetFileText(Path & FileName)
            If InStr(Contents, "Attribute VB_Name = ") = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Invalid "; ModuleType; " file: "; Path & FileName
            Else
                VBName = Split(Split(Contents, "Attribute VB_Name = " & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34))(0)
                On Error Resume Next
                Set Module = .VBComponents(VBName)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not Module Is Nothing Then
                    .VBComponents.Remove Module
                    Set Module = .VBComponents.Import(Path & FileName)
                    Module.Name = VBName
                End If
            End If
            Set Module = Nothing
            FileName = Dir
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
    
Public Function GetFileText(FullFileName As String) As String
    Open FullFileName For Input As #1
    GetFileText = Input(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
End Function

Usage

ReplaceModules ThisWorkbook, "V:\Code Modules\Temp\"



thanks @TinMan but I get the Run-time error 50021: Application-defined or object-defined error with your code

@user21948159 I'm working on a fix for the filename names that do not match the Attribute VB_Name.

@user21948159 which do you want to use the bas file name or the Attribute VB_Name?

I'm new to VBA. Is the Attribute VB_Name the attribute that can be set in the Properties window in VBE? If so, I would like the Attribute VB_Name to be set to what the bas file name is i.e. the module codename = bas file name

@user21948159 read: VBA Planet - VBA Attributes
